My time series graph look wrong, how can I make it connected normally
Here is my code for timeseries line graph
plt.figure(figsize=(25,5))
plt.plot(dt['Period'], dt['Sales_quantity'], marker = 'x', linestyle = '-')
plt.title('Sales Quantity over a period of time')
plt.xlabel('Period')
plt.ylabel('Sales Quantity')
plt.show()




I guess you have multiple values for the same 'Period'? Try eliminating duplicates.

Could you also show a sample of your data, e.g. dt[['Period', 'Sales_quantity']].head(10)?

And also could you please sketch how you would like the plot to look like

I think I want to eliminate multiple value as Deadly Pointer said. How can I make each point have only one value? like make an average for each quarter. Thank you in advance for your help

You could group your datapoints by period and compute mean() on the resulting aggregated dataframe.
For example, consider the following dataframe with just 4 rows.
dt = pd.DataFrame(
     data={
        'Period': ['Q1 2015', 'Q1 2015', 
                   'Q2 2015', 'Q2 2015', 
                   'Q3 2015', 'Q3 2015'], 
        'Sales_quantity': [99, 101, 
                           105, 107, 
                           102, 104]})

Aggregate by Period:
df = dt.groupby('Period').mean()
df['Period'] = df.index

Plot the results together with the original data:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,5))
ax.plot(dt['Period'], dt['Sales_quantity'], 
        marker = 'x', linestyle = '-', label='original data')
ax.plot(df['Period'], df['Sales_quantity'], 
        marker = 'o', linestyle = '-', label='group by period')
plt.xlabel('Period')
plt.ylabel('Sales Quantity')
plt.title('Sales Quantity over a period of time')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


